# How work the force_feedback topic in Phantom Omni?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I execute `rostopic echo /omni1_force_feedback` don't happens anything and I don't now how works.

How can I test that this topic works good?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74770/how-work-the-force_feedback-topic-in-phantom-omni?/) by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This topic has to be used to ***set*** force vector on device, not to **get** it. Technically there is no force sensors in any of PHANToM devices, so there is no way to obtain such information. Though you can calculate it based on spring-damper model giving displacement as its input.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-09-17**:
How can I set de force on device?  a command with parameters??

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-17**:
Send a message to appropriate topic, e.g. to /omni1_force_feedback. To set the force from command line use `rostopic pub`. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics and http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_pub